# How to search filenames in a log file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, svn, build, text-parsing

I have made a script that builds the .vbp  files in the company that I work. I want to build only the last changed files. By using timestamps I will build more unecessary files as some people test the files. So I thought that the best solution is to store the latest commits from svn to a log file (which I already do) and search in this file for the .vbp files and then build them. How can I search for the *.vbp wildcard and build these files only?

Below I have the part of code that stores the logs from the client trunk in `$outputFileClientCustom2` and builds `$factory`, but I want factory to be take from the XML that I have the last commits stored.

```
$clientTrunk | % {
  svn log -l 1 -v --xml $_ 2>&1 |
    ft -AutoSize -Wrap |
    Out-File $outputFileClientCustom2
}

& Get-ChildItem $factory -Include *.vbp -recurse | foreach ($_) {
  Write-Host 'Building ------->' $_.FullName;
  & $vb6 /out $outputFileClient $_.FullName /make | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `svn log --search ARG --search-and ARG`? See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.search

Comment: ok, it makes it easier but again how do i extract the name from the xml ? i use $xml.log.logentry.paths.path but it takes the state of the log as well (M for modified and so on).